# using maplibregl, multiple images are being overlayed on map when using local wms service

Tags: wms, maplibre-gl, ncwms1.2

Through ncmws2, I am publishing my local dataset.
[snapshot of the published dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcfKv.png)

But when I want to use the same through the WMS service of maplibregl, multiple images are overlayed on the map.

[snapshot of the multiple images being overlayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUOZ5.png)

a snapshot of the code using the maplibregl+wms service is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Add a WMS source</title>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Add an external Web Map Service raster layer to the map using addSource's tiles option." />
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css' />
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.js'></script>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
        html, body, #map { height: 100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    const map = new maplibregl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/streets/style.json?key=l1pwXTuM4tkfkKv0lOMc',
        zoom: 1,
        center: [-74.5447, 40.6892]
    });

    map.on('load', () => {
        map.addSource('wms-test-source', {
            'type': 'raster',
            // Use the tiles option to specify a WMS tile source URL
            // https://maplibre.org/maplibre-style-spec/sources/
            'tiles': ['http://localhost:8080/ncWMS2/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetMap&SRS=EPSG:3857&VERSION=1.3.0&DATASET=1&STYLES=&CRS=CRS:84&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&LAYERS=spi&bbox=33.875,10.875,60.125,33.125&format=image/png&transparent=true'],
            'tileSize': 512
        });
        map.addLayer(
            {
                'id': 'wms-test-layer',
                'type': 'raster',
                'source': 'wms-test-source',
                'paint': {}
            }
        );
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also,
I have multiple timestamps in the dataset, any information on publishing and accessing the layer of each timestamp along with retrieving the time series data for a selected location would be of great help.

I have tried adding image sources, ideally, wms should fetch the georeferenced image from the server and place it as per the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the problem was the bbox fixed. Change it to **bbox={bbox-epsg-3857}** so the maplibre (mapbox) will figure out.

You can find this info here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/style-spec/reference/sources/

> By providing a URL to a WMS server that supports EPSG:3857 (or EPSG:900913) as a source of tiled data. The server URL should contain a "{bbox-epsg-3857}" replacement token to supply the bbox parameter.